# Salesforce LWC form not loading in external site due to browser cookie

Tags: lightning-web-components, delete, site.com, form, cookies

We have displayed a Salesforce LWC form in an external site, For a contact the LWC form is not loading when the same contact is trying to reload the site.

It works in this way:

1. If the contact is logged in to the portal, The form will not load when the site is
   reloaded.
2. If the browser is closed and reopened, the form loads (reason --> browser cookies are
   cleared)
3. Basically the form is not loading because of browser cookie (Cookie name --> sid,
   sid_client)

We need to know if there is any possibility to get the cookie / delete the cookie and show the form when the site is reloaded.

Comment: ... another approach would possibly be to make the form load even in the presence of "the cookie": Do you know, why the form is not displayed in its presence?